# What intrinsic property do metals have that causes their delocalisation?

Tags: electronic-configuration, metal

So I understand that electrons in metals delocalise completely and are free to move around. But my question is, why would something like Nitrogen not delocalise, whereas say Iron or Bismuth does? What is special about their orbital configuration that causes this?